# Как связать с десктопной программой онлайн словарь?

Tags: c#, синтаксический-анализ

Делаю переводчик для заучивания слов. Хочу, чтоб я вводил слово на немецком
и мне сразу выпадал перевод артикль (гугл не подходит) и произношение.
Например:

- [Lingvo Online](http://lingvopro.abbyyonline.com/ru/Translate/de-ru/Buch)
- [Translate.Ru](http://www.translate.ru/)

А можно как нибудь открыть окно того же самого лингво и когда пользователь вводит значения в программе, она бы открывала сайт (скрыто) и заносила в поле "перевести" его слово, а потом бы брала перевод, как бы типа с сайтом работаешь, но пользователь этого всего не видит, а получает только перевод.
И после того как ввёл слово, хотел бы получит список возможных переводов, что б уже решать, какое слово добавить в локальный словарь.
Как это связать с десктопной программой на c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не являюсь C#-программистом, но предполагаю, что тебе понадобится класс [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) 
Возможно есть какие-то готовые браузерные движки для C#, которые облегчат тебе жизнь - попробуй поискать.

По реализации 2 метода:

1. Законный: Если у подобных
   сервисов есть API, то лучше через
   него либо на основе договорённостей.
2. Незаконный: Отправляешь/получаешь
   данные и парсишь их - имитируешь
   работу пользователя. Посмотри в
   сторону "parser C#", "Парсер сайтов
   C#" - готовые примеры в интернете
   находил.